# Using the decreased variable in the next loop in php while loop

Tags: php, algorithm, variables, while-loop

I have a form which I expect it to update multiple rows in tableA

```
$val = isset($_POST['val'])? filter_var($_POST['val'], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT):'';
$id = isset($_POST['client'])? filter_var($_POST['client'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT):'';
```

TableA looks like below:

```
CREATE TABLE `TableA` (
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`client` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`amount` DOUBLE(5,2) NULL,
`balance` DOUBLE(5,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`status` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
--Sample Data
-- INSERT INTO `TableA` (`id`,`client`,`amount`,`balance`,`status`) VALUES
-- ('1','1','0','150','Balance');
-- INSERT INTO `TableA` (`id`,`client`,`amount`,`balance`,`status`) VALUES
-- ('2','1','0','150','Balance');
-- INSERT INTO `TableA` (`id`,`client`,`amount`,`balance`,`status`) VALUES
-- ('3','1','0','200','Balance');

  SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE client='1':

 +----+--------+--------+---------+----------+
 | id | client | amount | balance |  status  |
 +----+--------+--------+---------+----------+
 |  1 |    1   |   0.00 |  150.00 | Not Paid |
 +----+--------+--------+---------+----------+
 |  2 |    1   |   0.00 |  150.00 | Not Paid |
 +----+--------+--------+---------+----------+
 |  3 |    1   |   0.00 |  200.00 | Not Paid |
 +----+--------+--------+---------+----------+
```

From my form variables I have `$val=300` and client `id=1`. Now I want to update the rows where client is equal to `1`. Here is my attempt:

```
//
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM TableA 
                       WHERE client=:id and status =:st");
$query->execute(array(':id' => $id,':st'=>'Not Paid'));
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
     if($val>$row->balance){
          $newval = ($val-$row->balance);
          $bal = $row->balance;
          $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE TableA SET amount=amount+:bal, 
                                balance='0', status='Paid' WHERE client=:id");
          $update->execute(array(':bal'=>$bal, ':id' => $id));
     }else if($val==$row->balance){
          $bal = $row->balance;
          $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE TableA SET amount=amount+:bal, 
                                balance='0', status='Paid' 
                                WHERE client=:id");
          $update->execute(array(':bal'=>$bal, ':id' => $id));
     }else{
          $bal = $row->balance-$val;

          $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE TableA SET amount=amount+:val, 
                                balance=:bal, status='Balance' 
                                WHERE client=:id");
          $update->execute(array(':val'=>$val,':bal'=>$bal, ':id' => $id));
     }
}
```

After the above loop, I expect the following output:

```
 SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE client='1':

 +----+--------+--------+---------+----------+
 | id | client | amount | balance |  status  |
 +----+--------+--------+---------+----------+
 |  1 |    1   |   0.00 |  150.00 | Not Paid |
 +----+--------+--------+---------+----------+
 |  2 |    1   | 100.00 |   50.00 |  Balance |
 +----+--------+--------+---------+----------+
 |  3 |    1   | 200.00 |    0.00 |   Paid   |
 +----+--------+--------+---------+----------+
```

The loop does not change `$val` value. Therefore, instead of getting my expected output I get all the amount rows updated. How can I get the desired output?

Comment: You assign the variable `$newval` but never use it.

Comment: @Barmar, how do I use it for the next loops?

Comment: Maybe you should use `$val = $val - $row->balance;`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your logic. When `$val > balance`, it's supposed to set `balance = 0`, so why does id 1 still have `balance = 150` in your expected output?

Comment: Never mind, I see that you processed id 3 first, so you used up the amount before you got to id 1.

Comment: @Barmar, when $val >$row->balance, the existing balance will be used to fill up the amount and the $val-$row->balance =newval will be generated. The newvalue will be used in the next loops instead of the old $val.

Comment: LIke I said, you should be assigning that to `$val`, not to `$newval`.

Comment: @Barmar, if you can solve this problem, I would be very happy. The main problem is every time the loops run it is using the $val and not $newval because the $newval is no longer there. That causes all the rows being updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decrease `$val` each time you use part of it to update a row. Also, break out of the loop when you use up all of `$val`.

The row you update should be where `id = $row->id`, not `client = $id`, because the latter will update all rows for the client, not just the current one in the loop.

And you should be calling `$db->prepare` in the loop, not `$db->query`.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM TableA 
                       WHERE client = :id and status = :st order by id desc");
$query->execute(array(':id' => $id,':st'=>'Not Paid'));
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    if($val>$row->balance){
        $val = ($val-$row->balance);
        $bal = $row->balance;
        $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE TableA SET amount=amount + :bal, 
                                balance='0', status='Paid' WHERE id=:id");
        $update->execute(array(':bal'=>$bal, ':id' => $row->id));
    }else if($val==$row->balance){
        $bal = $row->balance;
        $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE TableA SET amount=amount + :bal, 
                                balance='0', status='Paid' 
                                WHERE id=:id");
        $update->execute(array(':bal'=>$bal, ':id' => $row->id));
        break;
    }else{
        $bal = $row->balance-$val;
        $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE TableA SET amount=amount + :val, 
                                balance=:bal, status='Balance' 
                                WHERE id=:id");
        $update->execute(array(':val'=>$val,':bal'=>$bal, ':id' => $row->id));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is updating all the rows in field (`amount`) with 300 and the status of all the rows to `Paid`.

Comment: what could be the issue? I am waiting for your amazing solution. Thanks.

Comment: To be clear this is how `$val` runs in the loop: `first loop = 150`(first if), `second loop =150`(first if) and `third loop = 150`(second if).

Comment: On first loop, we do `$val = $val - 200;` so it should drop from 300 to 100.

Comment: Did you test it yourself? it updates all the rows to 300. Now I am trying with `goto`, It almost works fine except that it does not update the balance in one of the rows.

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. I'm not sure what's wrong with my logic, though.

Comment: this logic is very complex for newbie like me. If you can work out for me, I would be very very happy. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the answer and tested the code. You had the wrong `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` queries, and you were calling `$db->query` instead of `$db->prepare`. I was getting errors from the latter, I don't know how you didn't notice that.

Comment: Thank you very very much, barmar, This is working. Your code lets me update multi invoices in one go.